# How i return substring using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am cleaning a dataset, I want to extract some features from a Pandas series(and delete the row that hasn't these features).

Basically I want to turn this:

```
meter
Author: Stephen Duck Metrical foot type: iambic (-+) Metrical foot number: pentameter (5 feet)  Rhyme scheme: aa  
Author: Marko bulk Metrical foot type: anapaestic (--+) Metrical foot number: trimeter Rhyme scheme: ababcdcd
```

to this:

```
foot         feet_number
iambic       pentameter
anapaestic   trimeter
```

I've managed to do it with the code below,I make a copy of this series to use replace function.

It's not Pythonic and I'm sure it's not the most efficient use of pandas either. I loop through it twice to find the first feature , then another two loops to find the second feature .

This for the first feature (the same for the second with different pattern )

```
pattern1=r'.* Metrical foot type: '
pattern2=r'\( .* \) Metrical foot number: '

dataset['meter']=dataset['meter'].str.replace(pattern1, "")
dataset['meter']=dataset['meter'].str.replace(pattern2, "")
```

then a loop to delete rows that hasn't these two features.

Any ideas how this can be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `str.extract()` with the following expression:

```
foot type:\s+(?P<foot>\w+)
.*?
foot number:\s+(?P<feet_number>\w+)
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'meter': ['Author: Stephen Duck Metrical foot type: iambic (-+) Metrical foot number: pentameter (5 feet)  Rhyme scheme: aa', 'Author: Marko bulk Metrical foot type: anapaestic (--+) Metrical foot number: trimeter Rhyme scheme: ababcdcd']})

df[['foot', 'feet_number']] = df['meter'].str.extract(r'foot type:\s+(?P<foot>\w+).*?foot number:\s+(?P<feet_number>\w+)', expand=True)
print(df)
```

This yields:

```
                                               meter        foot feet_number
0  Author: Stephen Duck Metrical foot type: iambi...      iambic  pentameter
1  Author: Marko bulk Metrical foot type: anapaes...  anapaestic    trimeter
```

---

See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rIQyrw/1).

Comment: great, I just add one more line to remove cells that have NA values